# Before Update Event or After Update Event (MS Access 2013)

Tags: forms, ms-access-2013

I develop small database which gets bigger every day and I've got a situation with Before Update Event on one field.

Let's say I have main form which has subform based on the table (PONSt). The subform has one specific field (PONSt_PDV) which data depends on the other table (APP_PDV). When user updates that field (PONSt_PDV) directly in combo box, Before Update events is triggered and some calculations are done. That works perfectly!

The second situation (which is the reason for this question) is when user double clicks that combo box to open pop up form which contains the data from the other table (APP_PDV). In that pop up form user can edit, add or delete it's data and everything works great. There is a button on that pop up form which is used to get data (ID) from that table (APP_PDV), store it to the first table's field (PONSt_PDV), close the pop up form and get back to the first form (sub form on the first form, to be exact). After that, I want to recalculate other fields (in the first table PONSt) depending on the change in field (PONSt_PDV), but Before Update (or After Update) event in that case doesn't trigger at all.

What I'm doing wrong? Is there something that I can't see? Thanks!

Comment: Events on controls don't fire when you manipulate them through VBA, they only respond to user interaction on the form.  Simplest solution would probably be to tack on the recalc routine after your update.

Comment: Thank you! I've solved it with the procedure called from that sub.